# How to create multithreading method for getting file?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create method for getting file Stream by file name and expect that my method can work with multithreading but it fails... My code here:

```
public static class FileHelper
{
   private static object lockObject = new object();
   private static Stream fileStream;

    public static Stream GetFileStream(string filename)
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
            return fileStream;

        lock(lockObject)
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                return fileStream;
            }

            fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
            return fileStream;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: "it fails" isn't really a good description. Bear in mind that if multiple threads try to use the same stream, they'll play havoc with each other. Reading a single file with multiple threads is generally a bad idea anyway, assuming it's on a single drive.

Comment: I dont think he wants to use multiple threads to use the same stream, but rather wants a thread-safe class to do the reading/writing?

Comment: It's doesn't necessarily have to be the same stream to be a bad idea. It could be the same file.

Comment: Unclear: a) what the problems is b) what it is suppose to do.

Comment: It seems to be a thread-safe singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly what you are looking for is a thread-safe singleton pattern implementation. Here is a good article of how to do it in java, but it's pretty much the same in C#.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html